# force sequentially on integration parametrized test on maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, parallel-processing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have parametrized integration test, that I run with maven-surefire-plugin.

They use a wiremock server, which send different value for each parameters.

When I launch all the tests, they are not consistent , it's never the same test who are OK and KO. If I relaunch only the failed, more and more passed, until they are all OK.

I suspect a concurrence issue.

But ow Can I know if the issue is on maven , surfire, intelliji or in the Parametrized Runner?

How can I force maven or intelliji or Parametrized to run the test methode one by one, one classe by one?

The code:

```
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class InfoIT  {

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "cache: {0}")
    public static List<Object[]> getParameters() {
        return asList(new Object[][]{
                {"infoA"},
                {"infoB"},
                {"infoC"},
                {"infoD"}
        });
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
    public String cache;

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule siteServer = new WireMockRule(WIREMOCK_SITESERVER_CONFIGURATION);

    WebTarget infoClient = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(INFO_URL);

    @Test
    public void test_delete_is_ok_with_private_ip() {

        // when
        Response response = infoClient.path(format("/private/%s/test", cache)).request().delete();

        // then
        assertResponseEmpty(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could annotate the class `InfoIT` with `@NotThreadSafe` (from  net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0), this will make the tests run sequentially (source: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html). If that's what you are asking.